# Ensuring Unique Email Address in Documents

Tags: ravendb

I want to create or update a `UserAccount` entity with an `EmailAddress` property, whilst ensuring the `EmailAddress` is unique.  `UserAccount` has it's own `Id` property of type `long`, this is just so I can track each `UserAccount` entity, as using the email address as the document id would present issues if the user wishes to change their email address.

I've heard I could create a new collection called `UniqueEmailAddresses` that could be collection of empty (or near empty?) documents and the email address would be the actual document id.

Is this correct?  If I update both collections in one transaction, is this the best way to ensure that 2 documents with the same email addresses don't end up in `UserAccount` collection?  Does adding this extra collection with the user's email address as the id, cause any performance issues when dealing with millions of users?  Is it possible to create an empty document?  Am I going down the right path?

---

### EDIT

These are the available bundles, which bundle do I need to add to get the unique constraint features?

[image]

---

### EDIT 2

I've added the Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints DLL to the folder `~/App_Data/RavenDB/Plugins` (I'm using the embedded server) and changed my Document Store Provider to:

```
protected override IDocumentStore CreateInstance(IContext context)
{
    EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
    {
        DataDirectory = @"~\App_Data\RavenDB",
        UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
        Configuration = { Port = 8181, PluginsDirectory = @"~\App_Data\RavenDB\Plugins" }
    };

    documentStore.RegisterListener(new UniqueConstraintsStoreListener());

    documentStore.Initialize();

    return documentStore;
}
```

But it still doesn't show in the available bundles list and my call to `checkResult.ConstraintsAreFree()` wrongly returns `true` when I'm testing by breaking the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB has the notion of the unique constraints bundles that does all of it for you.

See the docs:
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/bundles/how-to-work-with-unique-constraints-bundle

Comment: I've tried what is mentioned in that article, but it doesn't seem to work.  I can't see the extra documents being created that handle the unique constraint.  I've noticed the article seems to suggest this is part of a bundle, but there is no option to switch it on in the embedded version (3.0.3660) I am using.  Also when registering the listener, should I do this before or after I initialise the document store?

Comment: Did you add the bundle?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've edited my question with a snippet of the available bundles that are displayed.  I'm not sure which bundle I need to add.

Comment: See installation here: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/bundles/unique-constraints

Comment: Thanks again, I've included more detail to the question as to what I've now tried after your last comment.

Comment: Please create a failing test and send it to the mailing list.